# Inserting to a table table which have Readonly primary key column

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

I was working with an application that uses sql server database. I was trying to insert a row into a table as shown below. This table has a primary key 'prodNum'. It's auto-generating key.

When I try to insert a row to the table as shown below,in line `intResult = oSglProdTableAdapt.Update(oCableRecDataSet, "ProdTable")` I'm getting an exception:

> {"Column 'prodNum' is read only."}

I'm not even setting value for 'prodNum' column while creating the datarow as you can see. But the update function trying to write the value for that column also. 
I tried to insert using Insert query in sql management studio software. There It's working fine. So I assume that the issue is with my code. Is there anything I'm missing?

```vb
    ' a record does not exist for the new Cable Product
    ' therefore insert a new data row in the ProdTable table

    ' clear the DataSet
    oCableRecDataSet.Clear()
    ' create the Data Row
    Dim oDR As DataRow = oCableRecDataSet.Tables("ProdTable").NewRow()
    ' populate the datarow with values
    'oDR("ProductIDNum") = 102
    oDR("ProductID") = ProductID
    oDR("DefinedDate") = DefinedDate
    oDR("OperID") = OperID
    oDR("CutsizeBased") = CutsizeBased
    ProdTable.AddDRofProdTable(oDR)
    ' add the datarow to the dataset
    oCableRecDataSet.Tables("ProdTable").Rows.Add(oDR)

' update the Database with values from Dataset with the Data adapter
  intResult = oSglProdTableAdapt.Update(oCableRecDataSet, "ProdTable")
```

---

```vb
Public Sub AddDRofCableDef(ByRef oDR As DataRow)


    oDR("Upper") = m_Upper
    oDR("Spec") = m_Spec
    oDR("IlUpper") = m_IlUpper
    oDR("IlLower") = m_lIlLower
    oDR("Spec") = m_Spec
    oDR("MeanUpper") = m_MeanUpper
    oDR("MeanLower") = m_MeanLower
    oDR("MeanUL") = m_MeanUL
    oDR("MeanLL") = m_MeanLL
    oDR("SUL") = m_SUL
    oDR("StartZone") = m_StartZone
End Sub
```

---

Stack Trace Follows:

> at System.Data.DataRow.set_Item(DataColumn column, Object value)    at
>   System.Data.DataRow.set_Item(String columnName, Object value)    at
>   ACMS.DBCableRecordsCommands.OnRowUpdated(Object sender,
>   OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs args) in
>   D:\Software\clsDBCableRecordsCommands.vb:line 956    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender,
>   OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter.OnRowUpdated(RowUpdatedEventArgs
>   value)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[]
>   dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable
>   dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataSet dataSet, String
>   srcTable)    at
>   ACMS.DBCableRecordsCommands.insertCableRecord(DBCableRecords Cable) in
>   D:\Software\clsDBCableRecordsCommands.vb:line 251

---

> UPDATE
>   One thing I noticed when I checked the generated datarow it has the ProdNum(Primary key) calculated, even though I'm not initializing that value. That may be the reason why sql server is not accepting. How to stop generation of primary key by datarow?

Comment: What are you doing in this line? _ProdTable.AddDRofProdTable(oDR)_

Comment: @Steve I'll update the qstn with that

Comment: Can you show how do you load the main DataSet? _oCableRecDataSet_

Comment: @Steve _ProdAdapt.FillSchema(oCableRecDataSet, SchemaType.Mapped, "ProdTable")_

Comment: I am guessing that there is generated code evolved. Check what the Insert statement in the generated code looks like. If it is trying to insert a value in the PK edit it. Remember that if you change anything with the database and regenerate the code, it will have to be fixed again.

Comment: @Mary can you make it clear? what did you mean by generated code?

Comment: Please add the SQL code contained in the `CommandText` of your adapter's `InsertCommand`.  Also, what is the type of the exception?  Can you post the stack trace as well?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Insert command: _"INSERT INTO CableDef (ProductID, Upper, Spec, IlUpper, IlLower, Spec, MeanUpper, MeanLower, DefinedDate, OperID, CutsizeBased, RangeUL, RangeUpper, MeanUL, MeanLL, SUL, StartZone, Blank1, Blank2, Blank3, Blank4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"_

Comment: I've added stack trace with the question

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "oCableRecDataSet" is the name of your DataSet, and the DataSet contains only one Table, so you can try this:

```
oCableRecDataSet.Tables(0).Columns("produNum").ReadOnly = false
intResult = oSglProdTableAdapt.Update(oCableRecDataSet, "ProdTable")
```

Comment: But dataset contains more than one table. I thought of this solution, But primary key should be read only, right?
And while creating Datarow I'm not initializing oDR("ProdNum"). It's set to auttogenerate

Comment: Is there any way to change it permanently?? Here I've to set it every time I'm doing anything table, right?