# Insert command behavior on adding a new datarow to the dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, oledb

In the below code I'm adding a new row to the Dataset *RecSet*. But while running the program, when I checked the parameters of the *Insert command* of the ProductsAdapt, all the parameters have value=*nothing*. On adding a new row, Parameters of Insert command will not get updated?

```vb
Private ProductsAdapt As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
Private RecSet As DataSet

RecSet.Clear()

Dim oDR As DataRow = RecSet.Tables("Products").NewRow()

oDR("ProductID") = ProductID
oDR("DefinedDate") = DefinedDate
oDR("OperID") = OperID

RecSet.Tables("Products").Rows.Add(oDR)
intResult = ProductsAdapt.Update(RecSet, "Products")
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behaviour. Consider the fact that there could be multiple rows to save in your `DataTable`. What values would you expect the parameters of your `InsertCommand` to have then?

What happens is that, inside that `Update` method, the adapter basically loops through the `DataRows` of your `DataTable` and, for each one that has a `RowState` of `Added`, it will set the `Value` of each parameter from the appropriate field of that `DataRow` and call `ExecuteNonQuery`.  That's why you have to specify the name of the source column for each parameter: so that the adapter knows where to get the data from for each row.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, Can I assume that the insertion of new row will happen even if _Insert command_ of the adapter is empty? Is that correct?

Comment: No you can't assume that. Based on what I said in my answer, if the `InsertCommand` wasn't set, what would the adapter set the parameters of and call `ExecuteNonQuery` on? If you use a command builder as well then, assuming certain conditions are met, it will generate the action commands for you on demand but, otherwise, you have to set them yourself.  Perhaps read [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases).

Comment: That's clear. I'm asking this since I have got an issue about writing into read only column. Products table has one primary key column named '_ProdNum_' (auto-incrementing). I'm not setting  value for that column while initializing the data row as you can see. And my _Insert command_ also doesn't have that column. But still i'm getting an exception *Column ProdNum is read-olny*. Can you please help with this?

Comment: That's a different question, so start a new thread.  Provide a title that describes that issue specifically and provide all the information relevant to that issue.  If I see that question and no one else has provided an answer, I'll do what I can.

Comment: I already asked that question. Didn't get the perfect solution. please see
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51725777/inserting-to-a-table-table-which-have-readonly-primary-key-column/51726019#51726019)